# SQL Inner join tables with identical column names

Tags: sql, inner-join, multiple-columns

I'm an doing an inner join on two tables with that have identical column names 'model' using the query below. It seems like I'm not getting both of these columns in the response. Is there some trick for dealing with this situation.

```
SELECT * FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 on table1.key1 = table2.key2
```

Comment: include `..., Table1.Model as t1Model, Table2.Model as t2Model` in your query.  I *think* you can add it to the *

Comment: This question must be incorrect. Since the names `key1` and `key2` differ, you should be getting both columns. Tell us more. Your RDBMS and version? Your client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to identify identical columns with aliases:

```
A.module as modulea, b.module as moduleb
```